# How do I sort photos from two identical smartphones based on exif data?

Tags: bash, photos, metadata, exif

**Description of Problem:**

I use Dropbox to synchronize photos from my smartphone to my laptop. I have used a command-line utility in the past called jhead to automatically sort and rename the photos based on the JPEG exif metadata.

For example, this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jhead -model GT-I9100 -n%Y/%m-%B/User1-%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S *.jpg 2> /dev/null
jhead -model P999 -n%Y/%m-%B/User2-%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S *.jpg 2> /dev/null
```

would rename each image based on the JPEG exif data. All photos that matched camera model GT-I9100, would be named with "User1" in the title, followed by the time and date the photo was taken. (i.e. ./2015/02-February/User1-2015-02-07_16:37:52.jpg), and the same for model P999 and User2.

Unfortunately, (or fortunately), User1 and User2 both have the same smartphones, so I can no longer sort based on camera model, as they are both SGH-I747M!

**Question:**

***Is there another way to differentiate between smartphones of the same make and model using exif metadata, or anything else?***

I'm curious about the following exif tags. Maybe there will be a unique identifier somewhere in there:

```
exif:MakerNote: 7, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 48, 49, 48, 48, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 1, 0, 12, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
exif:UserComment: 65, 83, 67, 73, 73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 232, 3, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 18, 120, 86, 52, 18, 120, 86, 52, 18, 120, 86, 52, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 96, 0, 38, 59, 49, 0, 232, 4, 36, 6, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 185, 212, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 253, 253, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 65, 0, 76, 0, 80, 72, 70, 74, 48, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 46, 80, 72, 70, 74, 48, 50, 67, 77, 76, 0, 48, 49, 56, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 49, 53, 48, 57, 48, 48, 50, 57, 48, 49, 48, 57, 48, 69, 53, 67, 48, 49, 48, 68, 48, 49, 49, 54, 48, 49, 49, 54, 48, 57, 54, 55, 19, 239, 5, 0, 55, 54, 0, 1, 18, 235, 38, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 84, 0, 85, 0, 78, 0, 65, 0, 2, 0, 208, 2, 232, 3, 80, 6, 207, 5, 207, 0, 16, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 254, 17, 2, 0, 64, 174, 1, 0, 193, 93, 255, 255, 255, 243, 255, 255, 145, 199, 255, 255, 22, 47, 1, 0, 89, 9, 0, 0, 145, 15, 0, 0, 32, 5, 255, 255, 79, 235, 1, 0, 0, 0, 70, 76, 70, 76, 2, 0, 83, 86, 78, 35, 22, 1, 103, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 2, 232, 3, 80, 6, 104, 5, 207, 0, 92, 0, 104, 5, 9, 21, 1, 0, 68, 9, 65, 9, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 78, 100, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 74, 0, 14, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 243, 1, 247, 255, 13, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 254, 0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 74, 75, 74, 75, 92, 14, 60, 249, 0, 0, 53, 255, 0, 0, 226, 148, 0, 0, 168, 146, 0, 0, 163, 145, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100, 88, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 232, 3, 0, 0, 80, 6, 0, 0, 207, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 131, 137, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 197, 84, 1, 0, 16, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 254, 17, 2, 0, 64, 174, 1, 0, 193, 93, 255, 255, 255, 243, 255, 255, 145, 199, 255, 255, 22, 47, 1, 0, 89, 9, 0, 0, 145, 15, 0, 0, 32, 5, 255, 255, 79, 235, 1, 0, 74, 75, 74, 75, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0, 129, 153, 9, 0
signature: f7359044760a12573c150b440ad2537ba848fb4ee795e51a36b1786d368421b9
```

Comment: Give it a look to the [Exif standard version 2.3](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf). Inside I found (pag 42) the _Lens Serial Number_  that should be unique, and the _Camera Owner Name_, when set. If that model did not save those info, you can always think to change the default name for the saved picture in one of the two device, or to store the pictures in folder with different names under the two devices... and so under dropbox :-)